# PostgreSQL How to use standard ERROR CODE and ERROR MESSAGE

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I would like to use standard ERROR message and code of PostgreSQL.
Right now, I can achieve my goal, but I would like to know the best way I can use.
Here is my current function in database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Dugong.Forget_Passwd_Add(
       in_Username varchar(255),
       in_randomURLs text
)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
        IF (SELECT Dugong.Users_isExist(in_Username)) THEN
        INSERT INTO dugong.Forget_Passwd (Username, randomURLs, used)
        VALUES (in_Username, in_randomURLs, FALSE);
        ELSE
                RAISE EXCEPTION USING ERRCODE = '20000', MESSAGE = 'Username not found';
        END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

My `Node Express` with `pg` module will use `client.query()`. 
`client.query()` has callback `err` and `result`. 
With my example in here. I can use `err.message` and `err.code` to get error message and error code respectively.
**Question :**
I want my code be able to `RAISE` any error from database side not restrict only my specific error code.
How can I do that?

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699958/postgresql-custom-exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raise` to throw both custom and standard exceptions.

Reference standard exceptions either by it's code:

```
raise sqlstate '22012';
```

or by name:

```
raise division_by_zero;
```

Here is the [list of defined error codes and names](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html); more information about `raise`: "[Errors and messages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)".

Comment: Suppose. I want my code be able to `raise` any `error` beyond `username not found`. For example `disk is full` error and any error I can not imagine right now. Do I need to hardcode for case by case?

Comment: Either hardcode, or maintain your own mapping for error codes and messages (just like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699958/postgresql-custom-exceptions suggests).

Comment: Thank you. Although I am not fully understand your answer, but I will back with my study again later thank you.